# Is it possible to add a new Container once Pod is created?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-container

Suppose I have created a Pod having 1 container, now I want to add a second container to it, how can I do that?

Comment: It should be pretty unusual to run multiple containers in a single Pod, and for that matter to manually manage Pods.  I'd recommend creating a second single-container Deployment, and using Services to communicate between the two.

Comment: @DavidMaze Sidecar containers are fairly common in my experience. It depends entirely on the scenario whether you should use a sidecar container versus an additional deployment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, the answer is "no". Once you have created a Pod, you cannot add a new Container to it. [Read the official note](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/ephemeral-containers/):

> Since Pods are intended to be disposable and replaceable, you cannot
> add a container to a Pod once it has been created.

However, sometimes it's necessary to inspect the state of an existing Pod, for example, to troubleshoot a hard-to-reproduce bug. In these cases, you can run an [**Ephemeral Container**](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/ephemeral-containers/) in an existing Pod to inspect its state and run arbitrary commands.

But before you think that you can create an ephemeral container to run your application and add to a running Pod, please note that Ephemeral Containers are not appropriate for running applications because they lack guarantees for resources or execution, and they will never be automatically restarted